# How to save data in DataFrame from combination of List and Dict as show below

Tags: python, dataframe

Hello There I wants to save data in data frame

I have following type of data

```
data = [
{'time':1.00,'a':11, 'b':12, 'c':13, 'd':14}, 
{'time':2.00,'a':21, 'b':22, 'c':23, 'd':24},
{'time':3.00,'a':31, 'b':32, 'c':33, 'd':34},
{'time':4.00,'a':41, 'b':42, 'c':43, 'd':44}
]
```

I am little confused with above type of data structure.

Output I am expecting in DataFrame:

```
    Time    a    b    c    d
0   1.00    11   12   13   14
1   2.00    21   22   23   24
2   3.00    31   32   33   34
3   4.00    41   42   43   44
```

I am looking for solution which give result in least time

I have tried this code:

```
for d in data:
    print d
```

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Comment: _I have tried this code:_ What does that code have to do with what you're trying to do? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].